# Converting matrix data representation into meshgrid

Tags: matlab, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I calculated the function of interest $f(x,y)$ numerically in Mathematica. For consistency, I want to use Matlab for plotting.

I exported my function in the matrix form:

```
 test =

-1.0000   -1.0000   -0.4864
-1.0000   -0.6000   -0.2804
-1.0000   -0.2000   -0.0462
-1.0000    0.2000   -0.0462
-1.0000    0.6000   -0.2804
-1.0000    1.0000   -0.4864
-0.6000   -1.0000   -0.2997
-0.6000   -0.6000   -0.1526
-0.6000   -0.2000    0.1118
-0.6000    0.2000    0.1118
-0.6000    0.6000   -0.1526
-0.6000    1.0000   -0.2997
-0.2000   -1.0000   -0.1809
-0.2000   -0.6000   -0.0939
-0.2000   -0.2000   -0.0046
-0.2000    0.2000   -0.0046
-0.2000    0.6000   -0.0939
-0.2000    1.0000   -0.1809
 0.2000   -1.0000   -0.1809
 0.2000   -0.6000   -0.0939
 0.2000   -0.2000   -0.0046
 0.2000    0.2000   -0.0046
 0.2000    0.6000   -0.0939
 0.2000    1.0000   -0.1809
 0.6000   -1.0000   -0.2997
 0.6000   -0.6000   -0.1526
 0.6000   -0.2000    0.1118
 0.6000    0.2000    0.1118
 0.6000    0.6000   -0.1526
 0.6000    1.0000   -0.2997
 1.0000   -1.0000   -0.4864
 1.0000   -0.6000   -0.2804
 1.0000   -0.2000   -0.0462
 1.0000    0.2000   -0.0462
 1.0000    0.6000   -0.2804
 1.0000    1.0000   -0.4864
```

So that `test` is 36x3 matrix, where the columns are `x`, `y` and `f(x,y)`. Now I need to contour plot it.

However, it is not in the form of meshgrid. Any thoughts, how to quickly convert it in the form that can be plotted by `contour` function?

Comment: Why do you need it in `meshgrid` form? Why not just do `contour(f)`?

Comment: it produces very strange result. I am sure it is incorrect, as I plotted it in Mathematica

Comment: Plot it as `y,x,f(x,y)`?

Comment: Can you explain in more details please

Comment: `contour(test(:,2),test(:,1),test(:,3))`?

Comment: There is an error: `Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.`

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't actually look at the distribution of your data. Your data are already 2d-plaid in the proper order, as if from `meshgrid`. So what I meant is actually `contour(test(:,1),test(:,2),test(:,3))`. But the error in your previous comment makes little sense to me... Oh, right, you copied the code from SO to your MATLAB. Don't do that. Type it out like regular humans to avoid non-printable characters messing up your code.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I didn't find better way to export the data. This is test only, I expect to export bigger data matrices. Thanks for the info, now the error is `Z must be at least a 2x2 matrix.`

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Though your question is solved, just because you "plotted it in Mathematica" doesn't mean anything.  The code / function / whatever you ran in Mathematica may also be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is regular (data set coincide with `meshgrid` but in vector form), then you can use `reshape`.

```
xgrid=6;
ygrid=6;
contour(reshape(test(:,1),xgrid,ygrid),reshape(test(:,2),xgrid,ygrid),reshape(test(:,3),xgrid,ygrid))
```

Another option is `tricontour` which will also work for irregular dataset

```
tri = delaunay(test(:,1),test(:,2));

figure;
tricontour(tri,test(:,1),test(:,2),test(:,3));
```

You can find `tricontour` at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38858-contour-plot-for-scattered-data/content/tricontour.m

If your surface is not convex,

then you need to remove some of triangulation from `tri` because of the nature of `delaunay`

Comment: Good idea, but OP clearly has a 2d-plaid mesh (and even regular, at that!), they are only facing logistical difficulties in ordering the points.

Comment: Andras Deak, correct. Dohyn, that is not exactly I am looking for.  thatks for the reference though

Comment: In that case, `reshape` will work. check my edited post. you might need to interchange `xgrid` and `ygrid`.